# Using create-react-app with electron-builder

Tags: electron, create-react-app, electron-builder

I have create a simple app using **create-react-app** and made the following changes to **package.json**

```js
{
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "electron-dev": "concurrently \"BROWSER=none yarn start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
    "preelectron-pack": "yarn build",
    "electron-pack": "electron-builder build -m",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "prettify": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "precommit": "yarn prettify",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  }
}
```

The **electron.js** file in the public folder

```js
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev')

let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1364,
    height: 768,
    webPreferences: {
      webSecurity: false
    }
  })
  mainWindow.setMinimumSize(1364, 768)
  mainWindow.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? 'http://localhost:3000'
      : url.format({
          pathname: path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html'),
          protocol: 'file:',
          slashes: true
        })
  )
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => (mainWindow = null))
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

On running the script `electron-pack` it gives me this error:
`not allowed to load local resource file:///index.html`

What could be the possible issue?

react-scripts version: **1.1.5**
electron-builder version: **20.28.2**

Comment: Have you already looked at the workarounds pointed out at: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5107 ?

Comment: @Neil I added `target: 'electron-renderer'` to the production configuration (**webpack.config.prod.js**), now the app loads with the index.html but the app file build by webpack doesn't seem to load. It shows that the js and css files are loaded in the Network tab of the devTools but the js file is not being executed

Answer (score 10):

I solved it.

The issue was with **BrowserRouter** of `react-router`. I had to change it to **HashRouter** and now all files and routes load properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You saved me. I was stumbling upon this from last 3-4 hours.